# NodeJS - The Package of mysql respects the names of the columns on having done an INSERT INTO... SET?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am developing a Rest API using NodeJS and MySQL as the atabase. I use the standard package of npm for MySQL. I am using the following statement at the moment of insert data into DB:

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE.TABLE SET ?
```

And the JSON that I am trying to insert is:

```
{
     name    : "Lorem",
     surname : "Ipsum",
     email   : "lorem.ipsum@mail.com"
}
```

But in the database the order of columns is:

[image: name/email/surname]

Do you know if the order of the fields matters, or does the NodeJS mysql package  respect the name of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

[According to the JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) the order of the attributes is not significant.

And as you don't have brackets arround keys (which is required for valid JSON) I suppose you're missing it with regular JavaScript object which [doesn't have ordering guaranties as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Comment: Thank you for all! I will correct this, and try it.